# Is it possible to display current Log4j2 (runtime) configuration in XML format

Tags: log4j2

I am using a 3rd party developed product, and they used log4j2 extensively in it. As my application runs on their framework, I don't want to overwrite their existing configuration and only want to write an appender to the existing runtime configuration on log4j.

Is there a way to see the existing runtime configuration of log4j2 instance in XML format?

I tried the following code but it gives me a blank xml.

Code:

```
        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder= ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
        LoggerContext ctx=(LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        builder.setLoggerContext(ctx);
        builder.writeXmlConfiguration(System.out);
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Configuration>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: "As my application runs on their framework, I don't want to overwrite their existing configuration..." - if they're providing a framework they shouldn't be providing you with a log4j2 configuration IMO because they have no idea what level of detail you wish to log. I would suggest the opposite approach - you SHOULD replace any existing configuration with your own well thought out configuration settings.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds logical !!

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. The [JMX client](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/jmx.html) that is one of the log4j2 modules does exactly that.

The functionality is provided by the [JMX package in the core module](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/tree/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/jmx).